# Add picture into lable using tkinter python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, widget, label

I write this below code that using tkinter GUI but there is an error that I cant solve it.Also I try some other ways like using PIL and ImageTk.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
photoImageObj = PhotoImage(file="pyImage.gif")              
lab = Label(root, image=photoImageObj).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

the error is this: `TclError: couldn't open "pyImage.gif": no such file or directory`

Can anyone help me to solve it? please

Comment: "no such file or directory" means exactly what it says. There is no file by that name in the current working directory.

Comment: Can you share an insight of the folder in which the following code and image is located

Comment: pyImage.gif, where is this file located?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hello Amata to solve your problem you should have the gif image file in the same directory as your python file is in.

If still it doesn't solve your problem you can copy the whole directory eg:

`file = r"C:\\pyImage.gif"`

this is just an example you can find yours and enter it.

Hope this would solve your problem

Comment: _"Hello Amata to solve your problem you should have the gif image file in the same directory as your python file is in."_ - this is false. Relative paths are relative to the current working directory, which might not be the same as the directory with the file.

Comment: What if the OP is using Unix or Linux, the directories start with a `/`  in such machines. First get the full information, rather than jumping to the conclusion that the OP is a Windows user.